# React: how can I execute function at exact minute every hour?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way I can execute the function at the exact minute (1 and 31 minutes for example ) every hour?
For example, it should be executed at:

```
08:01
08:31
09:01
09:31
10:01
...
```

Comment: Do you mean to execute only when the page is loaded? Or do you want something to happen in the background, also when the user closes the page - then you need backend for that.

Comment: When the page is opened only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at something like [Croner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/croner), this can evaluate and run Cron expressions.

This package can also return a list of the next N runtimes for a cron expression.

[Crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#1,31_*_*_*_*) is handy for parsing these expressions too.

For your example, the cron expression will look like `1,31 * * * *', meaning it will run at every minute and at thirty-one minutes past every hour.

```js
const pattern = '1,31 * * * *'

const job = Cron(pattern, () => {
  console.log('Job is running...');
});

const nextTimes = Cron(pattern).nextRuns(10);
console.log('Next run times:', nextTimes.map(d => d.toLocaleTimeString()));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/croner@6/dist/croner.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `cron` to do that, or do it from scratch with a `setInterval` to create a timer that will execute a callback every `n` millisecond (in your case every 60000).

Then in the callback you will only have to check the value of `new Date().getMinutes()` (1 or 31) and execute the function if the condition pass

```
setInterval(() => {
  const currentMinutes = new Date().getMinutes();
  if([1, 31].includes(currentSeconds) {
    // ...
  }
}, 60000);
```

If you want the function to be called at exactly 0 second, you can start with a `setInterval` executing the callback every second until the next minute, then use the above method

For example:

```
function forEveryMinutes() {
  setInterval(() => {
    const currentMinutes = new Date().getMinutes();
    if([1, 31].includes(currentSeconds) {
      // ...
    }
  });
};

const secondsInterval = setInterval(() => {
  const currentSeconds = new Date().getSeconds();
  if(!currentSeconds) {
    clearInterval(secondsInterval);
    forEveryMinutes();
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I wouldn't set an interval for 60,000 milliseconds. JavaScript does not guarantee that the function will run exactly and will drift.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you use **setInterval** or any other javascript package, keep it in mind that it will work only when the page is opened. Otherwise it will not work.

So, let say in your application, you have subscription system. Now whether user has opened the application or not, you have to expired subscription after specific time period. So, for these cases, you can't use javascript.

Now for these cases, you need **corn job**. You can also use **Database Triggers**.

Comment: I need it only when the page is opened

Comment: @domanskyi then use setinterval.